# How to get the syntax highlighter (Rust) to highlight formatted strings correctly in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, syntax-highlighting, rust-analyzer

For example, here I am expecting `sum` and `FILENAME` to be in different colors than the rest of the string literal:

[image: example screenshot]

I am using VSCode with rust-analyzer v0.4.1395 (Pre-release).

Seems like Markdown also has this problem:

```rust
println!("this is a formatted string with a {variable}, and an expression: {3+5}");
```

edit:

1. An example for my expectation can be seen in @Finomnis 's answer.
2. As noted by people in the comments, expressions such as `{3+5}` are not supported in formatted strings in Rust.

Comment: I see a string literal highlighted as a string literal. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you expected.

Comment: What is your expectation here?

Comment: Rust-analyzer can in fact do that. Markdown won't ever be able to do that, though, because it lacks the semantic context to differentiate between a string and a format string.

Comment: @cafce25 I'm expecting the content within the curly braces, and the curly braces themselves to be in a different color (As seen in Finomnis's comment). 
I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @VaderFuntime Note that `"{3+5}"` is not a valid format string. Complex expressions cannot be used in format strings, only simple variable names.

Comment: @SirDarius updated the original question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's theme dependent:
Dark+ (default dark):
[image: default dark+ theme]

Noctis Obscuro:
[image]

Edit: it's a theme setting: [vscode editor-semantic-highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-semantic-highlighting)
settings.json:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Noctis*]": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires semantic information, because not every string literal is a format string, and thus cannot be done by syntactic highlighting.

rust-analyzer handles this though, with semantic highlighting.

Besides, full expressions like `3+5` are not supported in format strings.

Comment: Point taken about the full expressions in formatted strings.
Do you have any idea though why doesn't the highlighting seem to work as expected for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running VSCode 1.74.2 and rust-analyzer v0.3.1394, and it works without a problem:

[image]

With rust-analyzer 0.4.1395 (PreRelease), it looks the same to me.

Note that while rust-analyzer is still loading (spinning circle in the bottom bar), or if rust-analyzer encountered an error (displayed red in the bottom), only the VSCode internal Rust highlighting is enabled, which can not highlight strings syntactically:

[image]

Comment: Weird. rust-analyzer definitely finished loading, but still, looks wrong.
Also tried downgrading to the release version, no change.